# I need Jquery crop picture plugin

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I need some plugin that crop picture before uploading it to the server. Do any body know some plugin or any thing to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using this one which outputs coordinates that you can then use server side.

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper